# GitHub Actions Running Twice on Merge of PR

Tags: github, github-actions

I have a GitHub action with the following triggers:

```
name: Continuous Integration

on:
  schedule:
    - cron: "0 */3 * * *"
  push:
    branches:
      - master
      - preview
  pull_request:
    types: [ opened, synchronize, reopened ]
    branches:
      - master
      - preview
```

It seems to be running twice when a PR is merged in - I see the following:
[image]
AND
[image]

I would expect only to see the one for Push to Preview (because I have the event type for PR as only opened, synchronized, and reopened).

How can I get my PRs to only build once when merging?

Comment: This is the expected behaviour according to the triggers you set on your workflow, there is this [interesting thread](https://github.community/t/trigger-workflow-only-on-pull-request-merge/17359) on the Github Community that could give you some insights. But basically, there is no `on` condition to do it exactly as you want at the moment.

Comment: is that because I'm doing something that isn't best practice? this seems so standard and basic

Comment: in my case it's not that I want the action only to run on merge - it's that I want the action only to run ONCE on merge

Comment: I added an official answer with what I understand is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in [this POST (and thread)](https://github.community/t/trigger-workflow-only-on-pull-request-merge/17359) on the Github Community.

You can achieve what you want using this trigger condition:

```yaml
on:
  pull_request:
    types: [closed]
```

And then use this `if condition` in your job to guarantee it will run only **if the PR has been merged**:

```yaml
jobs:
  build:
    if: github.event.pull_request.merged == true
    steps:
      ...
```

*note that the quotes around `true` in the GitHub thread cause it to fail*